# Using PDFBox to detect colored or strikeout text in a large PDF document

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

Is it possible to define simple code using PDFBox (or other Java library) to process a (large) PDF document and report the text that appears in a specific color (e.g., red) or strike-through. The strike-through or the color could appear anywhere, including in the middle of word (e.g., the text "lion" with the "l" colored and the "n" strike-through).

Any idea towards a solution would be great. I need to find the parts where there is a specific color or strike-through and manually revising the whole (large) PDF document would be difficult and error-prone, so I'm trying to find an alternative and reliable solution...

**Update:**
Based on the help provided and the posts reference, I made some progress, but this is still causing me problems...

I'm trying to:

1. Detect colored text different from black and write it to the standard output. This seems to work fine except that some newlines are not added in the output (apparently, when there is no explicit newline in the input PDF).
2. Detect strikethrough text and write it to the standard output. I cannot manage this to work at all. I've tried many options with no success.

Any idea is welcome!

I include below my current code:

```
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.*;
import org.apache.pdfbox.util.*;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.*;
import org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.*;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.state.*;
import org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.color.*;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.color.*;

public class PDFStyledTextStripper extends PDFTextStripper
{
    boolean globalDifferentFromBlack = false;
    String currentGlobalLine = "";
    
    public PDFStyledTextStripper() throws IOException
    {
        super();
        registerOperatorProcessor("re", new AppendRectangleToPath());
        addOperator(new SetStrokingColorSpace());
        addOperator(new SetNonStrokingColorSpace());
        addOperator(new SetStrokingDeviceCMYKColor());
        addOperator(new SetNonStrokingDeviceCMYKColor());
        addOperator(new SetNonStrokingDeviceRGBColor());
        addOperator(new SetStrokingDeviceRGBColor());
        addOperator(new SetNonStrokingDeviceGrayColor());
        addOperator(new SetStrokingDeviceGrayColor());
        addOperator(new SetStrokingColor());
        addOperator(new SetStrokingColorN());
        addOperator(new SetNonStrokingColor());
        addOperator(new SetNonStrokingColorN());
    }

    @Override
    protected void writeString(String text, List<TextPosition> textPositions) throws IOException
    {
        for (TextPosition textPosition : textPositions)
        {
            boolean st = determineIfStriketrhough(textPosition);
            if (st == true) 
            {
              System.out.println("Striketrhough detected in: " + text);
            }
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void processTextPosition(TextPosition text)
    {
        //System.out.println("(" + text.getX() + ", " + text.getY() + ")");        
        //System.out.println("Processing text position...");
        super.processTextPosition(text);
        PDColor color = getGraphicsState().getNonStrokingColor();
        boolean differentFromBlack = determineIfColorDifferentFromBlack(color);

        if (differentFromBlack == true)
        {
          globalDifferentFromBlack = true;
          currentGlobalLine = currentGlobalLine + text;
        }
        else
        {          
          globalDifferentFromBlack = false;
          if (currentGlobalLine.equals("") == false)
          {
            System.out.println(currentGlobalLine);
            currentGlobalLine = "";          
          }
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * Write the line separator value to the output stream.
     * @throws IOException if there is a problem writing out the lineseparator to the document.
     */
    protected void writeLineSeparator( ) throws IOException
    {
        //output.write(getLineSeparator());
    }

    boolean determineIfColorDifferentFromBlack(PDColor color)
    {
        try
        {
          PDGraphicsState graphicsState = getGraphicsState();
          int rgb = color.toRGB();
          if (rgb != 0)
          {
            //System.out.println("RGB value: " + rgb);
            return true;
          }
          else
          {
            return false;
          }        
        }
        catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        
        return false;
    }        

    boolean determineIfStriketrhough(TextPosition textPosition)
    {
        //System.out.println("Font: " + textPosition.getFont().getName());
        
        if (rectangles.stream().anyMatch(r -> r.strikesThrough(textPosition)))
        {
            System.out.println("StrikeThrough detected!");
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    class AppendRectangleToPath extends OperatorProcessor
    {
        public String getName()
        {
            return ("AppendRectangleToPath");
        }
        
        public void process(Operator operator, List<COSBase> arguments)
        {
            COSNumber x = (COSNumber) arguments.get(0);
            COSNumber y = (COSNumber) arguments.get(1);
            COSNumber w = (COSNumber) arguments.get(2);
            COSNumber h = (COSNumber) arguments.get(3);

            double x1 = x.doubleValue();
            double y1 = y.doubleValue();

            // create a pair of coordinates for the transformation
            double x2 = w.doubleValue() + x1;
            double y2 = h.doubleValue() + y1;

            Point2D p0 = transformedPoint(x1, y1);
            Point2D p1 = transformedPoint(x2, y1);
            Point2D p2 = transformedPoint(x2, y2);
            Point2D p3 = transformedPoint(x1, y2);

            rectangles.add(new TransformedRectangle(p0, p1, p2, p3));
        }

        Point2D.Double transformedPoint(double x, double y)
        {
            double[] position = {x,y}; 
            getGraphicsState().getCurrentTransformationMatrix().createAffineTransform().transform(
                    position, 0, position, 0, 1);
            return new Point2D.Double(position[0],position[1]);
        }
    }

    static class TransformedRectangle
    {
        final Point2D p0, p1, p2, p3;

        public TransformedRectangle(Point2D p0, Point2D p1, Point2D p2, Point2D p3)
        {
            this.p0 = p0;
            this.p1 = p1;
            this.p2 = p2;
            this.p3 = p3;
        }

        boolean strikesThrough(TextPosition textPosition)
        {
            Matrix matrix = textPosition.getTextMatrix();
            // TODO: This is a very simplistic implementation only working for horizontal text without page rotation
            // and horizontal rectangular strikeThroughs with p0 at the left bottom and p2 at the right top

            // Check if rectangle horizontally matches (at least) the text
            if (p0.getX() > matrix.getXPosition() + textPosition.getWidth() * .1f || p2.getX() < matrix.getXPosition() + textPosition.getWidth() * .9f)
                return false;
            // Check whether rectangle vertically is at the right height to underline
            double vertDiff = p0.getY() - matrix.getYPosition();
            if (vertDiff < 0 || vertDiff > textPosition.getFont().getFontDescriptor().getAscent() * textPosition.getFontSizeInPt() / 1000.0)
                return false;
            // Check whether rectangle is small enough to be a line
            return Math.abs(p2.getY() - p0.getY()) < 2;
        }
    }

    final List<TransformedRectangle> rectangles = new ArrayList<>();
    Set<String> currentStyle = Collections.singleton("Undefined");
}
```

Comment: I made some progress, but this is still causing me problems... I updates my original question and added my current code. Any idea or suggestion would be great!

Comment: With the Lion example there is no issue. The problem of newlines may appear if the colored text continues in letter beyond 1 line. Regarding the strikethrough text I did not manage to get it working in any example at all.

Comment: Here there is a sample file: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/92c1fb6b1320c561c82358ce5242a5ce20210621083104/dbef43 (I just modified the text for testing purposes). With this example I realized that my proposed code seems to be failing also to recognize some colored text.

Comment: Your `PDFStyledTextStripper` reminds me very much of [my old answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40039407/1729265) the code in which was developed with PDFBox 1.8.11. Which version are you using?

Comment: Your code only checks for rectangles drawn using the **re** instruction. In the old answer referred to above doing so sufficed because there *the underline and strike-through effects in the sample document are generated by drawing a rectangle* (using **re**) *under / through the text line which has the width of the text line and a very small height.* In your example document, though, strike-throughs are drawn as rectangles each using a **m**oveto and four **l**inetos. Thus, you have to improve your code to also find such paths.

Comment: I'm using version 2.0.24 of PDFBox. Anyway, I think that the modifications suggested are out of reach for me, as they seem to require deep knowledge of PDFBox and the structure of the PDF documents. I'm afraid I will need to try to find the strikethrough text manually through the whole document. Besides, there seem to be also some problems with the code I posted regarding the detection of colored text (it does not seem completely reliable, according to the sample PDF file posted). Thank you for all the suggestions.