# How to detect strikethroughs in Amazon Textract

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-textract

I have some documents with deletions (strikethroughs) and I need to detect if there is deletions in a document or not. Example: A pupil has written an assignment and mistakenly misspelled a word. So he put a line over the word to show the word is wrong (deletion).

Is there any possibility to detect this line?

Comment: Similar to: [Amazon Textract to identify strike through text from pdf file - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72452745/amazon-textract-to-identify-strike-through-text-from-pdf-file)

Comment: See also: [How to identify strike-out text from PDF files using Python - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72601927/how-to-identify-strike-out-text-from-pdf-files-using-python)